# Export datasets to a specific column,row in Excel

Tags: c#, excel-2007

I'm exporting a dataset to an existing Excel sheet using c# programming language. Hence i need to specifiy the exact column and row (Column G, Row 3)which the data to be inserted. Please note that the dataset has only 1 column. i have mentioned the coding that im using. But it doesn't pass the dataset to the location that i need. Please help

```
dt = compareDataTables(Oracle, MIT);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;  

        //inserting to Excel file
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(textBox1.Text, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
            {
                DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[j, i];
                xlWorkSheet.Cells["3", "G"] = cell.Value;
            }
        }
        xlWorkBook.Save();
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);
```

Comment: what problem your getting here? why xlWorkSheet.Cells["3", "G"]  is hardcoded?, its over writing the data everytime

Comment: I'm sorry. I was able to rectify the issue. The changes have been done and the file has been saved at C drive. thanks for your reply

Comment: If u dont mind could u please let me know how to accept it coz i cant vote for my own post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why xlWorkSheet.Cells["3", "G"] is hardcoded?, its over writing the data everytime